# TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _pubnubReact.default')

Tags: react-native, pubnub

I am new at React-Native and try to create Tic-Tac-Toe game using Pubnub and React-Native.

Well i am using following tutorial which is available at

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/multiplayer-mobile-tic-tac-toe-react-native-ios-android-part-one/

As per instruction given in tutorial i am completed.

The error comes in App.js file.

Here is App.js file code

```js
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';
     import {Platform,StyleSheet,View,Alert,Text,} from 'react-native';
     import Game from './src/components/Game';
     import Lobby from './src/components/Lobby';
     import shortid  from 'shortid';
     import Spinner from 'react-native-spinkit';
     import prompt from 'react-native-prompt-android';

              export default class App extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.pubnub = new PubNubReact({
              publishKey: "********************",
              subscribeKey: "*******************"

      });
           this.state = {
                username: '',
                piece: '', // Creator of the room is 'X' and the opponent is 'O'
                x_username: '', // Username for the room creator
                o_username: '', // Username for the opponent
                is_playing: false, // True when the opponent joins a room channel
                is_waiting: false, // True when the room creator waits for an opponent
                is_room_creator: false, 
                isDisabled: false // True when the 'Create' button is pressed
          };
    this.channel = null;
    this.pubnub.init(this); // Initialize PubNub
    }
```

I got error at **this.pubnub = new PubNubReact**

**Error is TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _pubnubReact.default')**

Version i am use as follows

"pubnub": "^4.28.4",

"pubnub-react": "^2.0.0",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "0.63.2",

Please help me Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[PubNub React](https://github.com/pubnub/react) library has been thoroughly changed since this article was written and therefore is no longer compatible. To fix this issue, you need to install an older version of `pubnub-react` dependency.

```
$ npm install pubnub-react@1
```